# Special character error in coldfusion cfm pages

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

We are using CF MX7 for one of our applications.

When we enter a set of characters to search for through the application CF throws out an error stating the below:

> Element USER_NAME is undefined in URL.

The error occurred in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MISWEB\lci\userNavigator.cfm: line 2

```
1 : <CFSET login_id = #url.user_login#>
2 : <CFSET user_name = #url.user_name#>
3 : <CFSET user_id = #url.user_id#>
```

This is occurring when we enter a login ID to search for that has an # character in it 0952#2. so basically, i understood that the problem is with the  login ID that we are entering, but we cannot ask the user to change his login ID. is there an alternate way to change the code in such a way that it accepts these values?

```
<CFSET login_id = #0952#2#>
```

hence the error is being thrown out at the second line where it is not accepting the username as it is not correct. Is there any way we can include the # present in the login ID provided inside the declaring #..# open and close # function?

Comment: And if i provide only 0952 in the search, i am getting the search results.

Comment: You'll need to escape the URL parameter so that hashes (#) don't appear. The browser sees the hash and doesn't even send it to the server, because it indicates an on-page location. Try using `escape(document.formName.user_name.value)` in JavaScript before submitting the search form. This will send it in the URL in an encoded format (`%230952%232%23`), which you can then decode when you set it to `user_name`.

Comment: You don't usually need to put # # in <cfset> statements, see http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html

Answer (score 4):

Because the search form is performing a `GET` request, the form fields are added to the URL. The problems is the hashes (#) are being interpreted by the browser as an on-page location, so nothing after the first hash in the URL is even being sent to the server, which is why ColdFusion says it doesn't exist.

To overcome this, you'll need to encode the hashes before submitting the form. You can do this with JavaScript and the form's `onsubmit` handler.

```
escape(document.formName.user_name.value);
```

This will send the `user_name` in the URL in an encoded format (`%230952%232%23`), which you can then decode when you set it to user_name.

```
<cfset user_name = urlDecode(url.user_name)>
```